# Asp.net core 2.0 PostAsync fails on IIS 7.5

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-7.5

Everything fine while running on Visual Studio 2017 RC, however it fails when deployed to IIS.

Code,

```
    private void ConnectApi()
    {
        var jsonCredentials = new
        {
            username = AppSettings.ApiUserName,
            password = AppSettings.ApiPassword,
            hostName = AppSettings.ApiHostName
        };

        var request = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonCredentials), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");           
        var url = string.Format("{0}", AppSettings.Api_BaseUrl + AppSettings.Api_Authenticate);
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var response = client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), request).Result;
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseBody = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                string authorizationToken = string.Empty;
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseBody))
                {
                    dynamic jsonContent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseBody);
                    AccessToken = jsonContent["authorizationToken"];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the exception details,

```
var response = client.PostAsync(new Uri(url), request).Result;

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: Access is denied
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncBuffered>d__58.MoveNext()
```

Any idea?

Comment: I noticed that trying to get an async operation `Result` on ASP.NET Core didn't work very well. Maybe changing your method to `async` would help.

Comment: Based on exception text `Access is denied` and how you populate credentials it looks like you have wrong credential values in `AppSettings`  if publishing to IIS. Show us how you populate `AppSettings`.

Comment: You *really* need to learn how asynchronous programming works: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/async

Comment: @ChrisPratt yes will, for now could you please advise how my above code can be changed to overcome the issue?

Comment: *Use async properly*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing Application Pool identity from ApplicationPoolIdentity to NetworkService solved the problem.

Any expertise can explain as what solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The Application Pool, as defined in Microsoft documentation, is essentially a Windows account, and each possible Identity Pool has different privileges. The ApplicationPoolIdentity is the least privileged account and, as a result, does not have Windows rights to access network resources.

On the other hand, as the documentation indicates, the NetworkService has access to network resources.
Note that there is another identity pool with more rights thant he NetworkService, that is the Local System.

As mentioned in the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/developer/webapps/iis/www-authentication-authorization/understanding-identities)